# After Angular Migration (from 12 to 14) still have vulnerabilities related to "d3-color vulnerable to ReDoS"

Tags: angular, angular-migration

After Angular migration to 14, I have updated my "@swimlane/ngx-charts" to "20.1.2" and "d3" to "7.8.4",but after running command npm install still having 5 high severity vulnerabilities in my project:
[image]
[image]

how to fix those vulnerabilities as I am already using latest version of ngx-charts and d3.

Answer (score 0):

Add this property in package.json:

```
 "resolutions":{
   "d3-color": "3.1.0"
  }
```

Then run this command:

```
npx npm-force-resolutions
```

Then run audit again; it should work:

```
npm audit
```